# Is asking whether something is deprecated off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I'm referring to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76202359/5825294).

Given the effort (I searched) and the comment from a high-rep user (stating the opposite of what I had found searching), isn't the question on-topic and well posed?

Comment: eh, not strictly? though i can understand people seeing the question as rather strange. You're asking if something is deprecated, after having looked at the documentation and finding that it isn't. What more authoritative source is there? Why would an answer here be more authoritative?

Comment: @KevinB, as far as I can tell, documentation can easily be outdated.

Comment: Not as easily as an answer on SO,

Comment: Documentation freshness in an official source is to Stack Overflow as a glacier calving is to [a bird sharpening its beak against Svithjod](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/255110-high-in-the-north-in-a-land-called-svithjod-there).

Comment: Note that while the question itself is somewhat ok (despite showing no research... but that's what downvotes are for) I don't think you really care about the answer to the question *as asked*... The likely question you actually have is "should I use/rely on that particular library" - and that one would be really off-topic.

Comment: *"I was therefore wondering if I'm just bad at searching."* <--- This is *half* of your question body. Come on.

Comment: Imo it's borderline asking for an offsite resource, mainly the lifecycle document for X. Since application lifecycle is dynamic, providing an answer that's not an online lifecycle document is of very little value, since I've encountered plenty of cases where things were deprecated early and also some where things were un-deprecated, so you rely on both the answerers knowledge being actual and the answerer updating the answer when this changes.

Answer (score 15):

It's a "meh" question.

It's not off-topic, far from it; it deals with programming and can be reasonably answered by someone who's expert in the field without needing to go into thesis mode.

But is it useful?  Meh.  Someone who's looking around on Google may find the answer in official documentation *faster* than seeing it on Stack Overflow.  Worst case scenario is someone sees the Stack Overflow answer and it *conflicts* with the official one, which is slightly more problematic, but still meh.

Overall...meh.  It's not off-topic but it's not the best question, either.  But this is just my personal assessment of it.

Just to be sure that everyone *gets* my meaning - **a question that is "meh" could be downvotable but is under no circumstances off-topic for that reason alone.**

Answer (score 7):

I agree with you - this is definitely not a recommendation question. While this question would likely be answered at least partially with a link to an authoritative source, that doesn't make it a recommendation question. In fact, if something can be answered with a citation from some authoritative source, that's actually a good thing because it means that answers can be defended factually.

Obviously, if such an authoritative source can be trivially located with Google, people are still free to downvote for that reason, but that wouldn't make the question off-topic. "Easily located on Google" is definitely not a close reason. I don't think that even that applies here, though - I'm not an expert on that particular topic, but this information doesn't appear to be particularly easy to locate.

The one thing I can think of that might have improved the question somewhat, though, is that it could have been helpful to reply to the original comment first to get more details on why that user thought that. This might have added a little more context to the question (or, at least, helped to establish it as a [notable claim](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim)).

Comment: "First sign of poisoning is blue color of the corpse" :) ... I believe most libraries deprecated implicitly by being abandoned rather than declared that way by maintainers... So while I agree that it could be answered with official links that answer may not be really helpful or practical... Library with no real changes in last 3 years (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commits/master) may be considered "abandoned" without any official note.

Comment: I wouldn't be against calling it abandoned, but calling it deprecated *because* it is abandoned is simply misinformation.